# what is the right order when use @ManyToOne @JoinColumns

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I use spring boot 3.2.2 and hibernate 6.4.1.

There are 4 entities

Customer.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_")
public class Customer {

    @Column(name = "tenant_id_")
    private Long tenantId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_")
    private Long id;

    // getters and setters
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getTenantId() {
        return tenantId;
    }

    public void setTenantId(Long tenantId) {
        this.tenantId = tenantId;
    }
}
```

Order.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "es_order_")
public class Order {

    @Column(name = "tenant_id_", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long tenantId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_")
    private Long id;

    // getter and setters

    public Long getTenantId() {
        return tenantId;
    }

    public void setTenantId(Long tenantId) {
        this.tenantId = tenantId;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

ReturnOrder.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "es_return_order_")
public class ReturnOrder {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumns(value = {
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "order_id_",
                    referencedColumnName = "id_",
                    nullable = false,
                    insertable = false,
                    updatable = false
            ),
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "tenant_id_",
                    referencedColumnName = "tenant_id_",
                    nullable = false,
                    insertable = false,
                    updatable = false
            )}
    )
    private Order order;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns(value = {
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "tenant_id_",
                    referencedColumnName = "tenant_id_",
                    insertable = false,
                    updatable = false
            ),
            @JoinColumn(
                    name = "customer_id_",
                    referencedColumnName = "id_",
                    insertable = false,
                    updatable = false
            )
    })
    private Customer customer;

    @Column(name = "order_id_", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long orderId;

    @Column(name = "tenant_id_", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long tenantId;

    @Column(name = "customer_id_")
    private Long customerId;

    // getter and setters
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order;
        this.tenantId = order.getTenantId();
        this.orderId = order.getId();
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
        this.customerId = customer.getId();
    }

    public Long getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }


    public Long getTenantId() {
        return tenantId;
    }


    public Long getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

}
```

ReturnOrderItem.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "es_return_order_item_")
public class ReturnOrderItem {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns(value = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "return_order_id_",
                    referencedColumnName = "id_",
                    insertable = false,
                    updatable = false
            ),
            @JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id_",
                    referencedColumnName = "tenant_id_",
                    insertable = false,
                    updatable = false
            )
    })
    private ReturnOrder returnOrder;

    @Column(name = "return_order_id_")
    private Long returnOrderId;

    @Column(name = "tenant_id_", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long tenantId;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ReturnOrder getReturnOrder() {
        return returnOrder;
    }

    public void setReturnOrder(ReturnOrder returnOrder) {
        this.returnOrder = returnOrder;
        this.returnOrderId = returnOrder.getId();
    }

    public Long getReturnOrderId() {
        return returnOrderId;
    }

    public Long getTenantId() {
        return tenantId;
    }
}
```

I want to create @ManyToOne relationship with @Joincolumns. Each relationship must contain tenant_id_ column.

but when I run the program.the error to me.

```bash
Referenced column 'tenant_id_' mapped by target property 'customer' occurs out of order in the list of '@JoinColumn's
```

the hole stacktrace is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Referenced column 'tenant_id_' mapped by target property 'customer' occurs out of order in the list of '@JoinColumn's
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1773) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1231) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:949) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Referenced column 'tenant_id_' mapped by target property 'customer' occurs out of order in the list of '@JoinColumn's
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.BinderHelper.findPropertiesByColumns(BinderHelper.java:531) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1910) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1859) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1768) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1432) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

I don't know what's wrong with these.

so,what is the right order if I relation to another entity with a none primary key column?

I put the project to a github repository.
https://github.com/ldwqh0/hdemo

Comment: Why do you have tenant_id_ included in join columns? IF the entity IDs are not unique without the tenant_id_ value, you should make a composite ID for them that includes the tenant id value.

Comment: Also see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16263

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh,this is a hibernate problem and has been resolved in 6.4.3.
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-17420

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).